# $\mathbb{C}P^n$-bundle over $BU(n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, classifying-spaces

The inclusion $U(1)\times U(n-1)\to U(n)$ induces a map $BU(1)\times BU(n-1)\to BU(n)$. [This source](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egermans/Chern1.pdf) claims that the fiber of this map is $\mathbb{C}P^n$. Could someone please explain why this is true?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo --- it should be $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ (as you can also see from the cohomology ring in the next sentence).

$BU(1)\times BU(n-1)\to BU(n)$ is the classifying map for taking orthogonal direct sum of a rank-$1$ bundle and a rank-$(n-1)$ bundle.  So the fibers are ways to split an $n$-dimensional vector space into the sum of $1$- and $(n-1)$-dimensional subspaces, but that is just choosing $1$-dimensional subspaces from a fixed $n$-dimensionsional one (the $n-1$ must then be its orthogonal complement), which is $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks.

Comment: A follow up question: how do we know Leray-Hirsch applies here? i.e. Why is the generator of the cohomology of $\mathbb{C}P^{n−1}$ the pullback of some element of the cohomology of $BU(1)×BU(n−1)$?